# Shell Script to move files from Infa_shared directory to a remote SFTP server

Tags: shell-script, ssh, sftp

My requirement is move a file (`DailyRenewalsYYYYMMDD.txt`) from infa unix server `data/infa_shared_SrcFiles/ABC/` to a remote server. I have created a shell script.

Below is the script that I am using and calling it via `Informatica` command task:

```
Parameters to Pass  
$1 - SOURCE  Path  
$2 - Remote Server Path  
$3 - PUT Logfile  
$4 - Email Subject & Body  
#######################################################################################

MFT_HOST='10.XX.X.XXX'  
MFT_USER='XXXXX'  
MFT_PSWD='*****'  
FAILURE_EMAIL='saurabh.s@xyz.com'  
SUCCESS_EMAIL='saurabh.s@xyz.com'  

cd $SCRIPT_PATH  
rm -f $LOG_PATH/$3  
 
sftp $MFT_USER@$MFT_HOST:$REMOTE_DIR_PATH <<< $'put $SOURCE_PATH' >> $LOG_PATH 2>&1  

#*I have used below command as well, even this didn't worked*#  
##sftp $MFT_USER:$MFT_PSWD@$MFT_HOST:$REMOTE_DIR_PATH <<< $'put $SOURCE_PATH' >> $LOG_PATH 2>&1  

export RC=$?  
if [[ "$RC" > 0 ]];  
then  
echo `date +"%m-%d-%y_%T"` >> $LOG_PATH/$3  
echo "ERROR: $4 Put File to REMOTE Server Failed" >> $LOG_PATH/$3  
mail -s "$4 Put File to REMOTE Server Failed" $FAILURE_EMAIL<<EOF  
"$4" File is NOT present in SOURCE PATH. Check log for details.  
EOF  
exit -1  
else  
echo `date +"%m-%d-%y_%T"` >> $LOG_PATH/$3  
echo "SUCCEEDED: $4 Put File to REMOTE Server Succeeded." >> $LOG_PATH/$3  
mail -s "$4 Put File to REMOTE Server Successfully Completed" $SUCCESS_EMAIL<<EOF  
"$4" File Successfully Transferred to REMOTE Server. Check log for details.  
EOF  
fi  
exit 0  

#############################
```

Upon executing this command via shell script from command task, I am getting error

```
THIS IS A PRIVATE COMPUTER SYSTEM ---  
USAGE MAY BE MONITORED AND UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS  
OR USE MAY RESULT IN CRIMINAL OR CIVIL PROSECUTION  
Permission denied, please try again.  
Received disconnect from MFT_HOST port 22:2: Too many authentication failures for MFT_USER  
Authentication failed.  
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

However, If I execute the above same `sftp` command in `putty` editor then it prompts me for password and upon giving the password, it copies the file at the remote server.

[image]

**Note:** I do not have `expect` utility installed, so I cannot use that.

Comment: I have achieved my requirement upto certain extent via below
cd $SOURCE_PATH
lftp sftp://$MFT_USER:$MFT_PSWD@$MFT_HOST -e "mput DailyRenewals*.txt; bye" >> $LOG_PATH/$3 2>&1


The only challenge is that if there are multiple files at a source path then the script fails. Can someone please suggest on this.

Comment: Can someone please help ...??